# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object -- com React js e Next js

Tags: javascript, react, front-end, autenticação

Estou fazendo um projeto clone do spotify com nextjs, nele estou criando uma página de login personalizada, esse é o código da tela de login:

```
import { getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react";

// Estilos 
import { Content } from "./styles/Login.style";

console.log(getProviders())

function Login({ providers }) {
  return (
    <Content>
      <img className="spotify-big-logo" src="https://links.papareact.com/9xl" alt="Spotify logo" />
      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button className="login-button">Login with {provider.name}</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Content>
  );
} 

export default Login;

export async function gestServerSideProps() { 
  const providers = await getProviders();

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
    },
  }
}
```

Essa página está me retornando o seguinte erro:

[image: print do erro]

Dei uma pesquisada e é por que o `provider` retorna um `undefined` quando não devia, como eu posso resolver isso?

Segue o código do nextauth:

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import SpotifyProvider from "next-auth/providers/spotify";
import spotifyApi, { LOGIN_URL } from "../../../lib/spotify";

// Função que recarrega o token
async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {

    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token.accessToken);
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken);

    const { body: refreshedToken } = await spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken();
    console.log("REFRESHED TOKEN IS", refreshedToken);

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedToken.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now + refreshedToken.expires_in * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedToken.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    SpotifyProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: LOGIN_URL,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  // página de login customizada
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      // Caso seja o primeiro login
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          username: account.providerAccountId,
          accessTokenExpires: account.expires_at * 1000,
        };
      }

      // Caso o token de acesso não esteja expirado ele vai utilizar esse mesmo token
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        console.log("EXISTING ACCESS TOKEN IS VALID");
        return token;
      }

      // Caso o token já tenha se expirado
      console.log("ACCESS TOKEN HAS EXPIRED, REFRESHING...");
      return await refreshAccessToken(token);
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      session.user.username = token.username;

      return session;
    }
  },
});
```

código do arquivo 'spotify'

```
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-node";

const scopes = [
  "user-read-email",
  "playlist-read-private",
  "playlist-read-collaborative",
  "user-read-email",
  "streaming",
  "user-read-private",
  "user-library-read",
  "user-top-read",
  "user-read-playback-state",
  "user-modify-playback-state",
  "user-read-currently-playing",
  "user-read-recently-played",
  "user-follow-read"
].join(',');

const params = {
  scope: scopes,
};

const queryParamString = new URLSearchParams(params);

const LOGIN_URL = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${queryParamString.toString()}`;

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
});

export default spotifyApi;
export { LOGIN_URL };
```

ps: todas as variáveis de ambiente estão corretamente declaradas no .env

Answer (score -2):

O problema é que o providers não tem valor inicialmente, já que ele setado por uma função assíncrona. Dois pontos da função Login vão quebrar por causa disso, no map e ao acessar provider.name.

Você pode verificar se o provider foi setado antes de retornar o bloco

```
return (
    !!provider && (
        <Content>
          ...
        </Content>
    )
);
```